# Proving $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\sin(n\theta)}\cos(\theta-\cos(n\theta))\,d\theta=0$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\sin(n\theta)}\cos(\theta-\cos(n\theta))\,d\theta=0$$

I really tried to solve this but I couldn't prove this. Of course this is true for natural numbers of $n$.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4QmP.jpg

the link is my solution

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: I believe you should end up with$$\begin{align*}I&=\int_0^{2\pi} \exp(\sin(n\theta)) \cos(\theta-\cos(n\theta))\,d\theta \\[1ex]&= \Re \int_0^{2\pi} \exp\left(i \theta - i\exp(in\theta)\right) \, d\theta \\[1ex]&= \Re \oint\limits_{|z|=1} z \exp\left(-iz^n\right) \, dz\end{align*}$$

Comment: @user170231 can you explain how?

Comment: Its under the complex definition of $z = e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$, and hence, $dz = ie^{i\theta}d\theta$ (u-substitution method applies here for your integral).

Comment: @UnexpectedConfusion I know and I did this but I couldn't prove that the integral is equal to zero I attached a link of my handwritten solution

Comment: this is an easy unit circle contour integral

Answer (score 2):

In fact, let $z=e^{i\theta}$ and then $d\theta=\frac{dz}{iz}$. So
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\sin(n\theta)}\cos(\theta-\cos(n\theta))\,d\theta=0\\
&=&\Re\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i\theta-ie^{i n\theta}}\,d\theta\\
&=&\Re\int_{|z|=1}ze^{-iz^n}\frac{dz}{iz}\\
&=&\Re(-i)\int_{|z|=1}e^{-iz^n}dz\\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray}
since $e^{-iz^n}$ is analytic in $|z|<1$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
&\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\sin(n\theta)}\cos(\theta-\cos(n\theta))\,d\theta\\
=& \ \Re \int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(\theta-e^{i n \theta})}\,d\theta
= \Re\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{(-i)^k}{k!} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(1+n k)\theta}d\theta=0
\end{align}
where $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{im \theta}d\theta=0$ per periodicity.